# C++ operator order evaluation

Tags: c++, operators, evaluation

I have the code and it gives me a compilation error.
I expected left-right operator order evaluation. The result of 'name += ":"' is string, but it looks like it evaluated ":" + "O" first. I didn't find any clear explanation why.

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string name("HELL");
  name += ":" + "O";
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [operator precedences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `name += ":" + "O"` is *grouped* as `name += (":" + "O")`

But this will result in a compilation error since `":"` and `"0"` are `const char[2]` types that decay to `const char*` pointers in that expression; and pointers cannot be summed!

From C++14 you could put the `+` into "string mode" with a *user-defined-literal* `""s`:

```
name += ""s + ":" + "O"
```

The grouping rules are hardwired into the language *grammar*, although it's convenient to think in terms of [operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Why not simply `name += ":"s + "O";`? Is there any difference?

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica: If there was then I'd be having a stern chat with my compiler vendor. But really you'd just use `":0"`;

Comment: In pre-C++14:  `name += std::string("") + ":" + "O"` maybe?

Comment: @YSC, Indeed although it's not quite as cute. And the Java guys do it the C++14 way. Although that language is comparatively hideous: disallowing operator overloading but then somehow allowing it for `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Or you could just remove the `+`: `name += ":" "0";`. The preprocessor concatenates adjacent string literals. That eliminates the temporary `std::string` object.

Answer (score 3):

According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator+` has higher precedence than `operator+=`, then `name += ":" + "O";` is interpreted as `name += (":" + "O");`, while `":" + "O"` is invalid, you can't add two pointers (`":"` and `"O"` would decay to pointer with type `const char*`).

You can add `()` to specify precedence, e.g. `(name += ":") + "O";`, it compiles but note that the part `+ "O"` becomes meaningless here. Or you might want `(name += ":") += "O";` as [@Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173499/c-operator-order-evaluation/59173535#comment104570302_59173535) suggested, it depends on your demand.

Comment: When you start to consider parentheses for breaking precedence, maybe, `(name += ":") += "O";`?

Comment: @Scheff Added to the answer; it might match OP's intent, I'm not sure. :)

Comment: @Scheff Wow, that chaining of `+=` looks so ugly to me. I don't quite know why since I happily chain `std::cout << ... << ...`, but doing it with `+=` just feels wrong. :)

Comment: @Frodyne Because of the `()`? Associativity of `operator+=` is right-to-left, without `()` `":" += "O"` will be evaluated firstly but it's invalid.

Comment: @Frodyne It really looks ugly with a few more arguments (getting closer to a Lisp program). In this case, it's probably better to repeat the LHS instead. Not that I think it makes a difference for the compiler but it's surely better for human eyes and mood.

Answer (score 0):

This expression statement with the compound assignment

```
name += ":" + "O";
```

in fact is equivalent to

```
name = name + ( ":" + "O" );
```

In this subexpression

```
( ":" + "O" )
```

the string literals are converted to pointers to their first elements. However the binary operator + is not defined for pointers. So the compiler issues an error.

You could split the original statement into two statements like

```
name += ":";
```

and

```
name += "O";
```

In this case there would be used the operator + defined for the class std::basic_string that accepts an argument of the type `const char *`.

Comment: (Nitpick: _"is equivalent to `name = name + ...`"_ - with the caveat that the expression `name` is only evaluated once).

Comment: @MaxLanghof In the context of the question it is totally unimportant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: But you have submitted a verbose answer so I too think you should mention it. (You notice that I avoid that can of worms completely in my answer?!)